# Join dataframes based on validity interval

Tags: r

I am looking for an elegant way of merging information in two data frames. The first data frame contains sales data at the transaction level (TRANSID) and includes a column for item number (ITEMNO), sales date (SALESDATE) and selling price (SALESPRICE). The second data frame contains information of recommended price (RPRICE) for each item and a certain date interval (VALIDFROM, VALIDTO), as the recommended price may changes over time. For each item, the intervals never overlap.

To investigate whether the selling price corresponds to the recommended price, I want to add the recommended price from the second data frame to the first data frame. However, as the recommended price changes, the join should be based on the criteria that SALESDATE is within the validity interval (VALIDFROM, VALIDTO).

```
 Data frame 1 example:

 ITEMNO    SALESDATE      SALESPRICE    TRANSID
 A         2016-10-01     555           1
 A         2016-11-04     555           2
 A         2016-12-23     555           3
 A         2017-01-12     555           4

 Data frame 2 example

 ITEMNO   VALIDFROM     VALIDTO       RPRICE
 A        2016-08-01    2017-01-10    555
 A        2017-01-11    2017-05-20    500

 Output should like this:

 ITEMNO    SALESDATE      SALESPRICE    TRANSID   RPRICE
 A         2016-10-01     555           1         555
 A         2016-11-04     555           2         555
 A         2016-12-23     555           3         555
 A         2017-01-12     555           4         500
```

In the case above, transaction 4 did not take place according to recommended price as the recommended price was changed the day before. Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: We can do a non-equi join